# Doctrine check fetchOne

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

My simple query:

```
    $list = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('liste l')
            ->where('l.id =?', $id)
            ->fetchOne();
```

$id = 123;

I know that there is no entry with the $id =123 in my database. When I count $list, I get the result 1. How do I know with my query or the result of my query that there is no entry with the $id = 123 in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var_dump gives me false!

So I just do a quick:

```
if ($list == FALSE) {
....}
```